# How can I display the values of an OrderedDictionary entry value that is an int[] array?

Tags: c#

I'd rather not create two separate the values into separate entries within the ordered dictionary but if there's a way to do what I'm trying to do here that'd be cool.

```
public OrderedDictionary spellResults = new OrderedDictionary()
{
    {"Test",new int[]{5,7}}
};

public void Main()
{
    //i'm trying to display the integers within "spellResults["Test"]" but i have no idea how i would accomplish this

    int[] pval= ((Array)spellResults["Test"]) as int[];
    Console.WriteLine(pval[0]+","+pval[1]);   
}
```

> Edit: Turns out the way I was doing it was also correct but I overlooked placing the OrderedDictionary in a class when I was using an online compiler to try and test it for the first time.
>    Whoops, thanks for the answers anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **static** with spellResults because you are using it inside the Main method which is known to be static method.use following tested code.

```
public static OrderedDictionary spellResults = new OrderedDictionary()
{

    {"Test",new int[]{5,7}}
};
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] pval = ((Array)spellResults["Test"]) as int[];
    Console.WriteLine(pval[0] + "," + pval[1]);
}
```

**Output Result**
[image]

Comment: Just realized the online compiler i was using didn't track my error so i forgot to put the dictionary in a class for testing. 
thanks.

Comment: This answer unnecessarily casts `spellResults["Test"]` to `Array` and is prone to [`IndexOutOfRangeException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.indexoutofrangeexception?view=netframework-4.7.1) if `pval` contains *less* than 2 elements.

Comment: For my purposes there will always be two values. so yeah.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (var number in spellResults["Test"] as int[])
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

However, you need to check the type of `spellResults["Test"]` first, as a `NullReferenceException` will be thrown if the conversion to `int[]` was not successful (i.e. it will try to iterate over `null`). You should perform a null-check beforehand:

```
var pval = spellResults["Test"] as int[];
if (pval != null)
{
    foreach (var number in pval)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
}
```

To print the numbers in CSV format, as per the original snippet, just replace the `foreach` with a [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.7#System_String_Join_System_String_System_String___) - that way, you also avoid  the program throwing [`IndexOutOfRangeException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.indexoutofrangeexception?view=netframework-4.7.1) at runtime if `pval` contains *less* than 2 elements:

```
if (pval != null)
{
    // this is bad, an IndexOutOfRangeException will be thrown
    // if pval contains less than 2 elements:
    // Console.WriteLine(pval[0] + "," + pval[1]);

    // use string.Join instead::
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", pval));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple `foreach` loop should suffice once you get the value, but you may want to change `OrderedDictionary` to `SortedDictionary` instead.

Update - updated to use `OrderedDictionary` after OP's comment.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var spellResults = new OrderedDictionary()
        {{"Test", new int[]{5, 7}}};
        var nums = spellResults["Test"] as int[];
        if (nums != null)
        {
            foreach (int num in nums)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

fiddle at: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pUXM3z

Comment: This might not require casting later on, but does require constraining the key-value types of the dictionary to `string` and `int[]` respectively.

Comment: I'm relying on using the OrderedDictionary class for this, because the rest of the values within the real "spellResults" entries are not just int[]. 

` 
var nums = spellResults["Test"];
    foreach (int num in (int[])nums){
        Console.WriteLine(num.ToString());
    } 
`
Does not work with the OrderedDictionary.

Comment: @DED - what error do you get? I tried it in .net fiddle and it seemed to work. https://dotnetfiddle.net/pUXM3z

Comment: @trashr0x - Thanks for the comment. if OrderDictionary is used the value will be of type Object isn't it? Then in that case we would need to cast to int[] isn't it?

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler correct, but as OP commented  *"the rest of the values within the real* `spellResults` *entries are not just* `int[]`", which makes a `SortedDictionary<string, int[]>` impractical as it can only store `int[]`s.

Comment: @trashr0x - yes, I agree. After OP's comment, SortedDictionary wouldn't work. Thank-you and updated.

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler it would work if the types of the `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` were constrained to `SortedDictionary<string, object>` instead - but then a cast would be needed, just as when using an `OrderedDictionary`.